# UTC Time displayed not in 24 hour format and not correct after 12am

Tags: javascript

I'm using a simple javascript to display the local time in my country, but it seems to be incorrect and not displayed correctly in the right order. After 12 midnight, by right the clock should reset to AM instead, but it keeps showing the time in PM.

Body:

```
<body onload="updateClock(); setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )">

//div tags, elements etc

</body>
```

JS:

```
function updateClock (){

var currentTime =  new Date();
var currentHours = currentTime.getUTCHours() + 8; 
var currentMinutes = currentTime.getUTCMinutes();
var currentSeconds = currentTime.getUTCSeconds();

// var bucurestiOffset = 3*60000;
// var userOffset = currentTime.getTimezoneOffset()*60000;

currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;

var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
  document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
}
```

The results are as such: 13:57 PM, when it supposed to be **1:57 AM**. Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `currentTime.getUTCHours() + 8` can be greater than 24. That's not how you deal with time zones.

Answer (score 1):

`currentTime.getUTCHours() + 8` can be greater than `24`, which leads to many errors (like the hour not being correct but also the day or month or year not being the right one).

You should look for libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to deal a little better with time zones and time formatting.

Comment: +1 for moment.js, but the code you showed here will be subject to the DST rules of the *local* time zone.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to do you're current method of `+8` for the timezone but accurately calculate it based on this function.

```
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset 
    // get UTC time in msec
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    return nd
}
```

[[source]](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/)